# Can't login after installing with, playing with, and uninstalling zsh

Tags: linux, bash, centos7, root, zsh

The really bad news here (I think) is that I use the root account to log in to my Centos 7 box.

The other day I saw an article about zsh, and installed it out of curiosity. Today I decided it's twaddle and I'd rather go back to regular bash, so I `yum remove`d it.

I now can't log back in.

What can I do to regain access to my box?  It's a Hetzner storage box, so I can boot (I think) into a rescue system via their web interface - but what steps do I need to take then, to regain full access?

Thank you!

Comment: couldn't you just upload a shell with `sftp`, eg. `put /bin/bash /bin/zsh` (I assume that the shell entry for root in `/etc/passwd` is still `/bin/zsh`)

Comment: or `rename /bin/bash /bin/zsh`?

Comment: Oddly I'm now in the rescue system, and /etc/passwd shows root's entry as being /bin/bash ....  So what do I change?!

Comment: try running it. is it `/bin/bash` also listed in `/etc/shells`?

Comment: I can't run it when I'm in a rescue system just browsing a mounted filesystem, can I?  /etc/shells contains /bin/sh /bin/dash /bin/bash /bin/rbash /usr/bin/screen

Comment: OK, sorted.  Like a dick I was running `vi /etc/passwd` instead of `vi etc/passwd` when in `/mnt` (or `vi /mnt/etc/passwd`).  Rookie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot the rescue system, mount the root file system, change in `/etc/passwd` the shell to `/bin/bash`, unmount and reboot.

Comment: Or log in as a normal user with `sudo` privileges.

Comment: `chsh` instead of manually editing passwd will reduce the risk of an error in your passwd file. It also can be run by less privileged users.

Comment: Thanks.  I've set a rescue system and reset the server through hetzner's web interface, and now when I try to ssh in with Putty I get "Connection refused".  Hopefully it's just taking a long time to perform the reset, but it's hard to know...

Comment: Their nmap shows port 22 open (presumably from inside their network), mine (from outside of their network) doesn't.  A configuration problem on their part I assume.  Awaiting a response...

Comment: Oddly I'm now in the rescue system, and /etc/passwd shows root's entry as being /bin/bash ....  So what do I change?!

Comment: OK, sorted.  Like a dick I was running `vi /etc/passwd` instead of `vi etc/passwd` when in `/mnt` (or `vi /mnt/etc/passwd`).  Rookie!